# Drupal - heartbeat - Avatar

Tags: drupal

Im trying to add the avatar into my heartbeat stream, or any additional token for that matter and I dont seem to be able to get it working.

I've edited the default message template "User adds a node, save user activity". Here is what ive setup as the single message

```
!avatar !username has added !node_type !node_title. !mail
```

**Then in rules ive setup the following variables:**

```
@avatar=[author:heartbeat-user-picture]
@username=[author:user-name-url]
@node_type=[node:type-name]
@node_title=[node:title-link]
@mail=[author:mail]
@types=[node:type-name]
```

I then use display suite to theme my heartbeat streams. But instead of getting the Avatar to display or the Authors email address I get the actual tokens.

My messsage I get is as following:

```
!avatar ankh2054 has added the following journal: test and journal entry . !mail
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked further and I found the issue, but still a little puzzled of how I can fix it. The reason is not displaying the picture is because I am using a custom node & content profile for my user profiles & therefore have assigned a custome CCK field for the user avatar. Display suite seems to only pickup the default picture that is assigned via the built in Drupal profile.

Any ideas ? thanks for yuor help so far :)

Comment: I have same issue with Gravatar integration, do you find any solution?